# Unable to update glibc to the latest version

Tags: centos, package-management, dependencies, glibc, redhat-satellite

We use Katello/Satellite 6 to manage our repos/pkgs and subscribe our servers to it. In the Katello Web UI it says that `glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64` and `glibc-common-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64` is an applicable update on the system, I'll then click to update and it'll say successful.. however nothing happens and Katello still shows me that it's an applicable update.

If I ssh to the server itself and try and do a `yum install glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64` it says no package found. This is on a CentOS 6.10 box.

We have some other packages such as nscd which rely on the latest glibc as a dependency as well so I'm just super curious why this is happening.

```
repo id                                                  repo name                                                         status
company_repos_centos6_extras               centos6_extras                                                          43
company_repos_centos6_os                   centos6_os                                                        6,695+18
company_repos_centos6_updates              centos6_updates                                                     305+54
company_repos_epel6                        epel6                                                               12,515
company_repos_katello_centos6              katello_centos6                                                          4
base                                                     CentOS-6 - Base                                                   6,695+18
dgoodwin-subscription-manager                            Copr repo for subscription-manager owned by dgoodwin                   8+2
epel                                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                      12,517
extras                                                   CentOS-6 - Extras                                                       46
foreman-client                                           Foreman client 1.20                                                      4
group_qpid-qpid                                          Copr repo for qpid owned by @qpid                                     25+3
logstashforwarder                                        Lostash Forwarder official repo                                          1
lynis                                                    Lynis YUM repo                                                          51
company                                                  company Repository for CentOS 6 - x86_64                               636
company                                           company RPM Repository for CentOS 6 - noarch                            37
pulp                                                     Pulp Community Release                                                  21
subscription-manager                                     Subscription manager repository from Candlepin                         8+2
update                                                   CentOS-6 - Updates                                                  329+54
repolist: 39,940
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
```

company_repos_centos6_os and base repos definitely have glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64 in there.

As requested in the comments, my `/etc/yum.conf` contains a repo that has `exclude=glibc-* kernel-*` and actually doing a `yum update` doesn't work.

Comment: What version of `glibc` is on the server right now? You can find out with `rpm -qa | grep glibc` or `yum list available | grep glibc`.

Comment: Hello @NasirRiley! Current version is: `glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64`

Comment: Doing a 'yum install glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64` says `No package glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
`

Comment: Are the necessary repos enabled on the system?

Comment: @NasirRiley They most definitely are. I've checked the repo itself to see if 212 is in there and it is. I'm really stuck at this point :( Does the kernel have to be on the latest version maybe?

Comment: If you just went to the URL of the repo to see if the package is there, that doesn't mean that the repo is enabled. Add the output of `yum repolist` and `grep -r -H enabled /etc/yum.repos.d/*` to your question.

Comment: Added yum repolist output to the main post

Comment: Also, add the contents of `/etc/yum.conf` to your question and see if it appears if you run `yum update`.

Comment: Is there a good way I can paste long output? There is a repo in here with that has exclude=glibc-* kernel-* and actually doing a `yum update` doesn't work. I'd like to poaste the entire output so that you can see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last comment reveals your issue.

Remove the exclude line from the repo file and/or `/etc/yum.conf`, run `yum clean all`, and try to install `glibc` again. That line is excluding the package(s) that you need to update.

Comment: You might want to find out why there’s an exclude on glibc. At this point centos6 is pretty stable and unlikely to change so one should try to keep it up to date.

Comment: Good call. I'll be sure to check before removing that line. Question.. if my yum update is failing due to dependencies of glibc, should I just exclude those as well for now?

Comment: @AlexanderDo Remove the exclude line and `yum update` will work.